# How to load an XML, defined in the c# startup-project, from a library

Tags: c#, xml, dll

I tried to look around for a best-practice to load an XML-File from the startup project in a C#-Solution.

I am building a library which should be able to load the following XML from the startup-project which is using the library. If possible the XML should NOT be visible to the enduser.
The XML-File uses a DTD, so I'm not sure if I could use the app.config to do this. Here an example of such an XML-File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE filter SYSTEM "filters.dtd">

<filter>
    <controltype-criteria type="Button">
        <event>TouchDown</event>
    </controltype-criteria>
</filter>
```

Does anyone have a recommendation how to do this?

Thank you for your reply! :)

Comment: Can you use an embedded resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it as a embedded resource to your assembly (startup project) and read it from there. Google knows the details.

Comment: Thanks, I declared the files as embedded ressources and want to access it over Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream, but the ExecutingAssembly seems to be my library/DLL so it can't find the XML. Do you know why only EntryAssembly seems to be the actual running assembly?

Comment: `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly` Gets the process executable of your current code. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` gets the assembly the currently executing code is defined in.